# Why is Nested RecyclerView with same orientation not used

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

[image: Sample UI : link]

I need to create a UI like above. The working is like when i click on an Order it needs to vertically expand with the products corresponding to that order.

I have tried using recyclerview for displaying the Orders. Then nested recyclerview for displaying the products when clicked. it didn't work as exppected.

Second approach was using the parent layout as scrollview. Scrollview has Linear layout as its child. I had manually inflate the orders as a view and adding to the linear layout's child. Thus i have acheived the same as recyclerview. This is not efficent, i think. Then on cliking the order, the products are displayed with the help of recycler view. Some how the products are listing. But when cliking on the last visible order item in scrollview, the product displaying recyclervie's size is small. Its random.

So what is the correct apporach create the UI ?
I have also heard about the expandable listview! using expandable listview is the correct way or is there any other way to create the same UI ?

Comment: use expandable listView

Comment: what was the problem you were facing in your first appraoch?

Comment: The nested items were facing size issues, some were like 2dp in height

Comment: If im using expandable Listview, Is it possible to display products as 3xN grids ?

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu I have already Posted image in Question

Comment: you can make this layout using recycler view but you have to notify on every item click